# How to fix Compile error creating the Login form in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating the from for my ms access database and I am running into a compile error when where "Me.txtUserName is not found.

This is for the Access database.

```
Dim User As String
Dim UserLevel As Integer
Dim TempPass As String
Dim ID As Integer
Dim UserName As String
Dim TempID As String


If IsNull(Me.txtUserName) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter UserName", vbInformation, "Username required"
    Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter Password", vbInformation, "Password required"
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
Else
    If (IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "tblUser", "UserLogin = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "' And UserPassword = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Username or Password!"
    Else
        TempID = Me.txtUserName.Value
        UserName = DLookup("[UserName]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
        UserLevel = DLookup("[UserType]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
        TempPass = DLookup("[UserPassword]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
        UserLogin = DLookup("[UserLogin]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
        DoCmd.Close
        If (TempPass = "password") Then
            MsgBox "Please change Password", vbInformation, "New password required"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUserinfo", , , "[UserLogin] = " & UserLogin
        Else
            'open different form according to user level
            If UserLevel = 1 Then            ' for admin
                DoCmd.OpenForm "Admin Form"
            Else
                DoCmd.OpenForm "Navigation Form"
            End If

        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Just follow the instructions at http://accesshosting.com/create-login-form-ms-access ...

Answer (score 1):

One immediate issue is that you have two variable assignments on a single line here:

```
 UserName = DLookup("[UserName]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" &                    Me.txtUserName.Value & "'") UserLevel = DLookup("[UserType]", "tblUser", "[UserLogin] = '" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "'")
```

These should be moved onto separate lines, or alternatively, the two variable assignments should be separated with a semi-colon.

Comment: It was just the way when blocking the code on overflow it appears